# Laravel iterate through unlimited hierarchy treeview non-recursively

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, treeview, iteration

I have implemented printing a categories tree to the page recursively:

```
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
         $tree .='<li>'.$category->title.'';
         if(count($category->childs)) {
            $tree .=$this->childView($category);
        }
    }
    $tree .='<ul>';

    return view('categoryTreeview',compact('categories','allCategories','tree'));
}

public function childView($category){                 
        $html ='<ul>';
        foreach ($category->childs as $arr) {
            if(count($arr->childs)){
            $html .='<li>'.$arr->title.'';                  
                    $html.= $this->childView($arr);
                }else{
                    $html .='<li>'.$arr->title.'';                                 
                    $html .="</li>";
                }                   
        }

        $html .="</ul>";
        return $html;
}
```

For DB structure: `id|title|parent_id`
Now I need to implement a iterative way to print a category tree to the page, and so far I have not found a solution.

I also tried:

```
 function buildTree($categories) {

    $childs = array();

    foreach($categories as $category)
        $childs[$category->parent_id][] = $category;

    foreach($categories as $category) if (isset($childs[$category->id]))
        $category->childs = $childs[$category->id];

     return $childs[0];
 }
$treez = buildTree($categories);
```

But I also don't know how to use this data non-recursively.

Could anyone lead me on the right path? Maybe I should combine `foreach` loops with some kind of while condition?

Answer (score 0):

In your category model:

```
public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
    
        
public function children()
{
    return $this->subCategories()->with('children');
}
```

In your model:

```
    public function getCategories()
    {
        $categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->with('children')->get();

        return view('category', ['categories' => $categories]);
    }
```

Blade (category.blade.php)

```
<div class="tree">
      @include('category-list-widget',['categories' => $categories])
</div>
```

Blade (category-list-widget.blade.php)

```
<ul>
   @foreach($categories as $category)
   <li>
      <a>{{$category->name}}</a>
      @if(!empty($category->children) && $category->children->count())
      @include('category-list-widget',['categories' => $category->children])
      @endif
   </li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

I did not test the code, Just wrote it here directly in the texteditor. I hope you get the idea.